# how to get value from array object in php

Tags: php

I need a value of place palampur from array

```
Array
    (
    [places] => stdClass Object
        (
        [id] => 1
        [images] => 
        [place] => palampur
    )
    [submit] => Submit Query
)
```

Comment: Something like `$var['places']->place`?

Comment: sorry it is not working dude

Comment: "places" is not a class but an object. Try with YourArray['places']->getPlace()

Comment: actually i use post the form and get under function like $_POST['places']->place   it is not working.anybody help me

Comment: Given the array dump in your question `$var['places']->place` is correct. If it doesn't work, like you say, you should give [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of that.

Comment: please add the form where you use from input elements as object array.?

Answer (score 0):

```
$object= new stdClass; 
$object->id = 1; 
$object->images = null; 
$object->place = "palampur"; 


$array = Array
    (
    'places' => $object,
    'surname' => 'Submit Query'
);


echo($array['places']->place);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value like this for accessing array we use "$array['places']" and to access object we use arrow operator "->".

echo $array['places']->place;

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
 //create blank object
   $obj = new \stdClass();
   $obj->id = '1';
   $obj->images = '';
   $obj->place = 'palampur'; 

   //create blank arrary
   $arr = array();
   $arr['places'] = $obj;
   $arr['submit'] = 'Submit Query';

   // change object to array     
   $output = (array) $arr['places'];

   echo $output['place'];
```